# Jquery class insertion

Tags: jquery, magento

So I have inherited some code and it isn't apparent to me how I can insert two classes where I need them.

so I have three relevent chunks of code some phtml, some jquery and the output html

phtml

```
<ol>
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <li 

    /*<!-- class="jcorgFilterTextParent" -->*/

    >
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"

            /*<!--class="jcorgFilterTextChild"-->*/

             >
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span>
                <?php echo $_item->getLabel(); ?>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                    <span class="count">(<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

If I insert the classes directly here I can get the first iteration to run smoothly but, none others. The jquery is where I am really confused.

```
  jQuery('.block-layered-nav .block-content #narrow-by-list dt').on('click', function (){
            if(jQuery(this).next('dd').css('display') != 'block'){
                jQuery('.active').slideUp('fast').removeClass('active');
                jQuery(this).next('dd').addClass('active').slideDown('slow');
            } else {
                jQuery('.active').slideUp('fast').removeClass('active');
            }


        });
    });
```

I would like to be able to insert the classes 'jcorgFilterParent' and 'jcorgFilterText' in the jquery but, I am not sure how to navigate the DOM to get them in the right place.

Finally just for some context

```
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span>Filter By</span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content toggle-content">
            <p class="block-subtitle block-subtitle--filter">Filter</p>
            <dl id="narrow-by-list">          
                <dt class="odd">Manufacturer</dt><dd class="odd">
                <input type="text" id="filter">
                <ol>
                    <li>
                    <a href="http://marssup1.nextmp.net/main.html?manufacturer=2664">3M<span class="count">(449)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="http://marssup1.nextmp.net/main.html?manufacturer=2665">Abanki Corp.<span class="count">(29)</span></a>
                    </li>
```

I really am a novice with Jquery so any advice would really be appreciated

Comment: `I would like to be able to insert the classes 'jcorgFilterParent' and 'jcorgFilterText' in the jquery ` Doen't mean much. Can you provide more info? Which tag/element is the target for these two classes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do:

Find all li's within the #narrow-by-list, and add the class to them.

```
jQuery('#narrow-by-list li').addClass('jcorgFilterTextParent');
```

Same idea, but with the <a> tags.

```
jQuery('#narrow-by-list li a').addClass('jcorgFilterText');
```

Since you're working in Magento, you might want to use prototype for this instead:

```
$$('#narrow-by-list li').invoke('addClassName', 'jcorgFilterTextParent');
$$('#narrow-by-list li a').invoke('addClassName', 'jcorgFilterText');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for helping me along eric. This is the solution :

*template\catalog\navigation\list-category.phtml*

```
    //Script for filter navigation
    jQuery('.block-layered-nav .block-content #narrow-by-list dt').on('click', function (){
        if(jQuery(this).next('dd').css('display') != 'block'){
            jQuery('.active input').removeAttr('id');
            jQuery('.active li').removeClass('jcorgFilterTextParent');
            jQuery('.active a').removeClass('jcorgFilterTextChild');
            jQuery('.active').slideUp('fast').removeClass('active');

            jQuery(this).next('dd').addClass('active').slideDown('slow');
            jQuery('.active input').attr('id' ,'filter');
            jQuery('.active li').addClass('jcorgFilterTextParent');
            jQuery('.active a').addClass('jcorgFilterTextChild');
            jQuery("#filter").jcOnPageFilter({animateHideNShow: false,
                      focusOnLoad:true,
                      highlightColor:'yellow',
                      textColorForHighlights:'#000000',
                      caseSensitive:false,
                      hideNegatives:true,
                      parentLookupClass:'jcorgFilterTextParent',
                      childBlockClass:'jcorgFilterTextChild'});

        } else {
            jQuery('.active input').removeAttr('id');
            jQuery('.active li').removeClass('jcorgFilterTextParent');
            jQuery('.active a').removeClass('jcorgFilterTextChild');
            jQuery('.active').slideUp('fast').removeClass('active');

        }


    });
});
```